# Row inside a Column in flutter - Reduce vertical gap between Rows

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Widget showGridList() {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: controller.plantCategoriesList.value.data!.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (
        context,
        index,
      ) {
        return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          Row(children: [
                Expanded(child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),

                  child: boxImage(index),
                  )
                ),

                Expanded(child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
             
                  child: showText(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    text: controller.plantCategoriesList.value.data![index].name!,
                    textSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    maxlines: 1),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              )          
            ]
          );
        },
    );
  }
```

This results in vast gap between individual Row elements.

What is the way to reduce this gap?

[image]

Comment: When you use 2 "Expanded" widgets in a row, the row will make itself as wide as possible and devide the available space in 2 equally wide parts. How to tackle this problem really depends what you want to achieve.

Comment: Or are you talking about the space between the rows (in the column)?

Comment: Oh, I am supposed to use One Expanded in one row! Didn't know that. @kazume

Comment: Again, depends on what you want to achieve really :) Expanded just means "expand to fill up the remaining space". If you use 2 next to each other, they will divide the available space between each other. You can tweak that even with giving the expanded flex values.

Comment: I simply removed one of those two widgets. That didn't help. I am basically talking about the "vertical" space between these rows which are the children of the column. @kazume

Comment: Ah I see ... you might want to remove the vertical padding then?

Comment: I added an example for you to try

Comment: Also bear in mind: using an Expanded in a Row will expand the widget's width, using an Expanded in a Column will expand the widget's height. Always expanding the main axis so to speak ...

Comment: @kazume I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Can you attach a picture of your desired output?

Comment: @MuhammadHussain please see the update

Comment: How about using `ListView.buidler` in this case. while  you are using  `crossAxisCount: 1,`

Comment: I would also suggest a listview here instead of a gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is because of your GridView, you can adjust it using `childAspectRatio` parameter in `gridDelegate`.

I also saw that your Column had no effect on the UI and those Expanded could also be unnecessary if you are willing to use MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround. Please look at the code below:

```
Widget showGridList() {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: controller.plantCategoriesList.value.data!.length,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
        childAspectRatio: 4/3, //adjust it accordingly
      ),
      itemBuilder: (
        context,
        index,
      ) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            boxImage(index),
            showText(
                color: Colors.white,
                text: controller.plantCategoriesList.value.data![index].name!,
                textSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                maxlines: 1),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of GridView.builder with a crossAxisCount of 1, use ListView.builder, as Yeasin Sheikh suggested.

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot? To be able to see what you're trying to do

Comment: Can you extend your code to include the enclosing class of the Column? What you can try right away though is setting the mainAxisSize of the Column to MainAxisSize.min

Answer (score 1):

The main issue not regarding the view of column or row but the Grid setup which you used hence the element are apart from each other remove the

```
return GridView.builder(
  itemCount: controller.plantCategoriesList.value.data!.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 1,
  ),
```

Remove this SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount with some other grid implementation your issue will be resolve. Check this and play with crossAxisCount

[SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount-class.html)

Comment: The crossAxisCount value set as 1 is causing issue. Please check and read the doc.